# MonoTouch: ResignFirstResponder() issues

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, xamarin.ios

I have a UIScrollView that stores a several UIViews.  I am using `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` to resize this `UIScrollView` when my keyboard pops up so that my viewable content area is only what is above the keyboard.  I do so with:

```
contentArea.Frame = new System.Drawing.RectangleF(0, contentArea.Frame.Top, 1024, 768 - contentArea.Frame.Top - r.Height);
```

Now when the keyboard disappears normally and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` fires, I can easily reset this with with following, and it works great:

```
contentArea.Frame = new System.Drawing.RectangleF(0, contentArea.Frame.Top, 1024, 627);
```

My issue is when I have to switch views, I need to hide this keyboard.  To do so I am calling `ResignFirstResponder()` on my `UITextField`.

- If I never enter any text into the `UITextField`, this works fine.
- If I do not scroll my view at all this works fine.
- However, if text was entered and there was scrolling, my `UIScrollView` returns to it's original size, but it now has an offset of how far it was scrolled * -1.  So if the offset was 50, it now is -50.  This means the top of my view is 50 pixels down the `UIScrollView`.

If I manually update the offset of the `UIScrollView`, it does not do anything. To actually fix this, I have to click inside a new `UITextField` and it fixes all my views in this `UIScrollView` to what it should be.

Any help on how to fix this is much appreciated!  I am updating from 5.0 to 5.1 hoping this is a bug that hopefully was fixed, but my hopes are low.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a solution to your problem but maybe an other way to archieve the functionality:
Instead of resizing you just scoll to the position (since you are using the UIScrollView).
An example can be found [here](http://spazzarama.wordpress.com/2011/09/07/monotouch-auto-scroll-uitextfield-or-other-views-hidden-by-keyboard/). In the example you would overwrite KeyboardGetActiveView and return the View that should be visible.